# Getting the pygame event of a key from a key

Tags: python, pygame

I want to be able to change the keys of a game and I am using tkinter to recieve the keys as chars:

```
key = 'a'
```

I want to convert those chars to pygame event variables like this:

```
pygame.K_a
```

and keep them in a dictionary that i have already prepared.

I have seen ways to do the opposite but i have not seen a way to do this.

I want to use the arrow keys and special characters, can i do it? or do i need to manually set up keywords?

Comment: I'm not sure of getting the point of this. So you want to capture the key pressed as character, and then convert it to a key event, instead of directly getting the key event. Why? If it's because you have objects in the game listening to key events and you want to be able to change the key mappings, the clean way to do this is to make your objects listen to "action" events instead of key events, an then map the key event to the action event.

Comment: Its because I don't get the chars directly from pygame. I take the chars from tkinter entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of the [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) constants art the ASCII values of the corresponding characters.

Instead of the the key

> ```
> pygame.K_a
> ```

the ASCII value of the character `'a'` can be used. The "value" of `'a'` can be get by  [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

e.g.

```py
pressed_a = False
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == ord(`a`):
            pressed_a = True
```

or

```py
k = pygame.key.get_pressed()
pressed_a = k[ord('a')]
```

Comment: How do i do it to special characters? (i.e Arrow up)

Comment: tkinter gives me a string from an entry

Comment: @Rabid76 What do you mean? I think its incoded in unicode if thats what you meant but i didn't mean special characters like greek letters or so i meant it as in special keys (backspace,end,home,tab,caps)

Comment: I dont know what to put in it, because python takes ascii characters and I dont know the ascii value of arrow up or is there is a char that represents it. Do you know?

Comment: @NimrodRappaport No, `ord()` works on unicode characters.